# Raspberry Pi 3B - Adding extra caps to make more stable power lines?

Tags: pi-3, power-supply

sometimes a flash on screen appears indicating power supply cannot deliver what Pi needs. Even when I have original power supply ( 3A) and total consumption of Pi doesn't exceed 500 mA. Maybe is power supply just "slow" and can't deliver spike currents. I wonder if somebody tried to add some extra capacitors to board or made some "shield" on GPIOs to make more stable power lines.

Sorry for bad English and thank's for your opinion.

Comment: Buy the official power supply https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-universal-power-supply/

Answer (score 1):

FIRST: A low voltage warning that occasionally flashes on your screen is not really anything to worry about. However, if it is affecting the operation of your RPi, it does need to be addressed.

Adding capacitance is a reasonable approach to such things, but you probably shouldn't approach it in a [*"willy-nilly"*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Willy+nilly) fashion.

First, understand that capacitors store energy, and energy is power over time. The capacitor's role is to help "carry the load" when the power supply voltage drops below the nominal voltage. Therefore, properly sizing the capacitor is necessary, and proper sizing requires we know two things:

1. How much power?
2. How much time?

I'll assume you don't know either of these values precisely, and so we will make some assumptions:

My RPi 3B+ draws about 400mA at 5VDC, or about 2 watts of POWER. I'll take a guess, and estimate that the transients triggering your low voltage dropouts last for 100msec, and that the voltage drop is 2V. In other words, you have a ***power shortfall*** of :

#### P<sub>s</sub> = V x I = 2V x 400mA = 800mw

The dropout lasts 100msec, so the ***energy shortfall*** is:

#### E<sub>s</sub> = P<sub>s</sub> x t<sub>s</sub> = 0.8 x 0.1 = 0.08 watt-seconds

So this is the amount of energy you need stored in a capacitor to make up the "shortfall". This can be translated into a capacitance value by using the formula for the energy stored in a capacitor:

#### E = 0.5 x C x V<sup>2</sup> *joules*

We must convert units & solve for C:

#### C = (2 x E joules) / V<sup>2</sup> x (1 watt-second / 1 joule) =

#### 2 x .08 watt-sec / 2<sup>2</sup> = .04 Farads or 40,000μF

Wow! [You can get them](https://www.mouser.com/Passive-Components/Capacitors/_/N-5g7r?P=1z0wo3h), but they're not cheap!

Is this a *really accurate* figure? No - of course not! I've made a wild guesses at the depth and the duration of your power transient. This was only to illustrate a process for sizing a capacitor. It also illustrates that sticking a capacitor (especially a big one) is not something to do *willy-nilly*.

Beyond the obvious considerations outlined above, adding a large capacitor on the output of a regulated power supply will significantly change its response curve, and may affect its stability.

#### In summary: Adding a big capacitor is not likely to be your best solution.

Better (more practical) solutions are:

1. Don't use cheap "knock-off" power supplies.
2. Use the shortest cable possible, with the heaviest wire gauge you can find. If you shop around, you can find USB cables with 22AWG wiring. The RPi power cable passes no data, so you only need a "charging" type of cable.
3. Don't power hard drives & other power hungry hardware from the RPi. Use a *powered hub* instead.
4. Get a USB power monitor - [for example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07JYVPLLJ). This will keep you informed on your power consumption.
5. Don't be afraid to experiment. This advice comes with caveats of course; you can ask questions here if you have any doubts.